# CKEditor 4 : Templates and allowedContent set in the config.js

Tags: plugins, ckeditor, config, toolbar

Is there a way of setting the allowedContent property to true for the given plugin from within the config.js file?

I've downloaded the minified, full version of CKEditor, which has each plugin minified in the main ckeditor.js file and plugin folders only hold the supporting files - hence the need to set it up from within the config.js file.

I know that I can set it globally by using config.allowedContent = true, but is it possible to do it on the per plugin basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download CKEditor-dev on github [here](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev) then edit plugins and finally build CKEditor your release with :

> ./dev/builder/build.sh

A "release ready" working copy of your development code will be built in the new dev/builder/release/ folder.